# cURL not requesting correct URL

Tags: php, apache, curl

I am messing around with cURL, first on my browser (chrome-extension)

URL:

```
http://www.example.com
```

HEADER:

```
POST /myfolder/myResponder.php?action=bla HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 56
```

DATA:

```
redirect=bla1
```

now the results I get are NOT from my myResponder.php .. those are from the insex.php in the root-folder (?) .. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: show you curl code completely. Also try to provide full path there in your curl request

Comment: tried GET instead of post ?

Comment: @ephemeral .. I need to have POST :/

Comment: @css  do what i saide in my first comment

Comment: @Alive to Die .. this is my complete cURL-request .. as I wrote, I am messing around with this chrome-curl-extension

Comment: @Alive to Die .. I did now provide the full path.. nothing :/